# How to view forms on a tablet and submit response back to SharePoint

Tags: 2007, infopath, xml

beginner SharePoint admin here looking for guidance.

We have a situation at our company where we want to be able to view company documents on tablets (which staff have due to their mobility requirements) and then digitally say that they have read and understood it.
Before we used to print them out and get everyone to sign that they had read it.

So Im just not sure of the best way.
We are using SharePlus Pro for Android to connect to SharePoint 2007. We can view documents on our tablets but just not sure how to approach this issue.

My guess is either creating a pdf form or an infopath form.
Which approach is best? (or is there another approach that is maybe free/opensource) and for that best approach, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with SharePoint list or libraries without using web services for SharePoint 2007 even then you will need an app which will access and cross-pond to that specific web services.

There isn't any free or opensource product out yet, however my company has a product which might give you some idea as for what you want to achieve.

http://www.boardpacks.com/Pages/default.aspx (I didn't mentioned it for advertisement but just to inform you about the product).

**Edit**

then you will need an android app with custom web services, so that you get user's input from tablet and then supply it to sharepoint library, I don't see any other way of doing it, unless you put a hyper link in each of document to click if they agree, this link will take you to a custom application, and on sharepoint develop a custom application page and in page_load method do the logic you want for example changing value of a document libraries column in DL.

I don't think it will be easy task for a SP Admin though.

Comment: No. SharePlus Pro is just a viewer of shared documents on SharePoint via an Android tablet. It doesnt create anything. It can but we won't be using it that way.

Comment: amended my answer.